# Angular on IIS inside ColdFusion

Tags: angular, coldfusion, iis-7.5, angular-router

I have an Angular application with lazy loading routes created and deployed to IIS7.5 on our internal network.  I've created URL Rewrite rules, and they work great, as long as I keep my index page with the (.html) extension.

However, I need the application to honor the Application.cfc in the root folder, which manages the session and forces a user to be logged in to access any page within the Application's subfolders.

I've tried changing the extension of the index to .cfm, and modified the URL Rewrites to point to that extension instead, but there is a problem.

If I navigate only to the index.cfm page, and then use routes, everything works fine...but if I refresh the page with the routes in the address bar, I get a HTTP 500 server error.

my base href="/e/myapp/"

my application.cfc is located at "/e/application.cfc"

my rewrite rules, for my routes, are setup as

```
<rule name="schedule">
    <match url="^schedule/*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
</rule>
```

changing the url to index.cfm results in the server error when the page is refreshed with the route "/e/myapp/schedule" or "/e/myapp/schedule/new", but not when it is "/e/myapp/index.cfm"

When the Http 500 error occurs, the requested url says that it is pointing to "/e/myapp/index.cfm"

If anyone has successfully done something like this, I would greatly appreciate any help.  If you need further clarification, please ask.

Comment: Hoping that someone can help out with this.  This is really a show stopper for us.

Comment: I will post the answer to my own question here once I verify the source of the problem.